# Angular build can't resolve material modules

Tags: angular, angular-material

When I try to build my application with `aot` set to true, I get a ton of errors about the `@angular/material` modules not being found (and it seems to be ***ONLY*** material modules). Here's my setup:

In my `material-barrel.ts` file, I export all the material modules like so:

```
export { MatTabsModule } from "@angular/material/tabs";

export { MatToolbarModule } from "@angular/material/toolbar";

export { MatTooltipModule } from "@angular/material/tooltip";

etc..
```

Then I have an angular module for all the material modules (`material.module.ts`):

```
import {
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatTabsModule,
  etc...
} from "./material-barrel";

const materialModules = [
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatTabsModule 
  etc...
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [...materialModules],
  exports: [...materialModules]
})
export class MaterialModule {}
```

In my `shared.module.ts` I import the material module and export it:

```
import { MaterialModule } from "@app/shared/material.module";

const importedModules = [
  MaterialModule,
  others...
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [...importedModules],
  exports: [...importedModules]
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

In my `app.module.ts`, I'm importing the shared module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    others...
  ]

  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

If I run `ng build` or `ng serve` with `aot: false` in `angular.json`, I see no errors. If I run either of them with `aot: true`, I get this error for every angular material module:

`ng serve` error message example:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../node_modules/@angular/material/tooltip/tooltip' in '*my project path*\src\app'
```

`ng build` error message example:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../node_modules/@angular/material/tooltip/tooltip' in '*my project path*\src\app'
resolve '../../node_modules/@angular/material/tooltip/tooltip' in '*my project path*\src\app'
  using description file: *my project path*\package.json (relative path: ./src/app)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    using description file: *my project path*\node_modules\@angular\material\tooltip\package.json (relative path: ./tooltip)
      no extension
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        *my project path*\node_modules\@angular\material\tooltip\tooltip doesn't exist
      .ts
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        *my project path*\node_modules\@angular\material\tooltip\tooltip.ts doesn't exist
      .tsx
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        *my project path*\node_modules\@angular\material\tooltip\tooltip.tsx doesn't exist
      .mjs
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        *my project path*\node_modules\@angular\material\tooltip\tooltip.mjs doesn't exist
      .js
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        *my project path*\node_modules\@angular\material\tooltip\tooltip.js doesn't exist
      as directory
        *my project path*\node_modules\@angular\material\tooltip\tooltip doesn't exist
[*my project path*\node_modules\@angular\material\tooltip\tooltip]
[*my project path*\node_modules\@angular\material\tooltip\tooltip.ts]
[*my project path*\node_modules\@angular\material\tooltip\tooltip.tsx]
[*my project path*\node_modules\@angular\material\tooltip\tooltip.mjs]
[*my project path*\node_modules\@angular\material\tooltip\tooltip.js]
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts 54:0-76 225:1490-1504 225:1506-1526
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
```

E.g. for the tooltip, If I take a look in `*my project path*\node_modules\@angular\material\tooltip\tooltip`, the file does indeed not exist there. However, I've found it here:

`*my project path*\node_modules\@angular\material\__ivy_ngcc__\fesm2015\tooltip.js`

and

`*my project path*\node_modules\@angular\material\fesm2015\tooltip.js`

and

`*my project path*\node_modules\@angular\material\esm2015\tooltip\tooltip.js`

What am I missing?

Comment: It's probably better to directly import the modules from the `@angular/material/*` entrypoints instead of exporting them into a dedicated file to then re-import them.

Comment: I did that to be able to import them all from one place wherever I need them. Turns out that was actually what was causing the issue. I changed my `material.module.ts` to import all the material modules directly instead of importing them through `material-barrel.ts`. Now I'm just wondering why this only breaks with aot compilation..